# Imprimir nombre columna como encabezados con bd postgresql y python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente codigo de una tabla de PostgreSQL, necesito que me imprima el nombre de columnas como encabezado, con Tabulate y Python, solo me sale la numeración de las columnas como encabezado, no se porque:

```
cur.execute("""select * from admin_eps""")

rows = [cur.fetchall()]

for row in rows:
    print(tabulate(row, headers="keys", tablefmt='fancy_grid', stralign='left'))
```

Este es el reporte de salida:

```
│   0 │         1 │ 2           │ 3                │ 4        │      5 │      6 │ 7                   │ 8                │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│   2 │ 890890890 │ Medimas     │ carr 26 n 10-20  │ Bogota   │ 520520 │ 311311 │ medimas@medimas.com │ wwww.medimas.com │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│   1 │     54321 │ COOMEVA EPS │ Calle 30 n 33-30 │ Medellin │ 252444 │ 320320 │ coomeva@coomeva.com │ www.coom.com     │
╘═════╧═══════════╧═════════════╧══════════════════╧══════════╧════════╧════════╧═════════════════════╧══════════════════╛
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque estás usando `headers='keys'`. Cuando usas esto se usan las llaves del diccionario pero como no es un diccionario se usa su índice.

Intenta usando tus propias cabeceras:

```
cur.execute("""select * from admin_eps""")

rows = [cur.fetchall()]
headers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']

for row in rows:
    print(tabulate(row, headers=headers, tablefmt='fancy_grid', stralign='left'))
```

Otra opción que puedes intentar es hacer uso de [`RealDictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=realdictcursor#psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor):

```
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

# ...    
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
cur.execute("""select * from admin_eps""")

rows = [cur.fetchall()]

for row in rows:
    print(tabulate(row, headers="keys", tablefmt='fancy_grid', stralign='left'))
```

Comment: O eventualmente se pueden usar los nombres de columnas de la tabla `headers= [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]` (si el op está usando `Psycopg`)

Comment: Podria ser, ya lo habia tomado como alternativa, pero mi duda es que con mysql no tengo ese problema, y postgresql si,?

Comment: @Jsierra2017 imagino que cada uno tiene su propia implementación de los cursores. No creo que sean iguales porque son diferentes motores de bases de datos.

Comment: Si uso Psycopg como API

Comment: @PatricioMoracho cierto, ahora que ha confirmado el uso de psycopg, podría funcionar.

Comment: Mi duda es si los dos (Mysql y Postgresql) aceptan injeccion SQL, por que la diferencia?:

Comment: @Jsierra2017en MySQL yo uso `cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)` y, en ese caso, supongo que tu código original funcionaría perfecto.

Comment: Claro, Cesar con Mysql no hay complique

Comment: @Jsierra2017 he actualizado mi respuesta con otra opción.

Comment: Excelente, Cesar la segunda opcion fue la solucion, se logra el objetivo, solo le faltaba los corchetes a la variable rows y listo. gracias

Comment: @Jsierra2017 lo agrego, disculpa, no tengo como probarlo en este momento :-p